# Maintaining two similar versions without duplication

Tags: lyx, revision-control

I have a long paper which I currently keep in two versions: one version for submission to a journal and another version for publication as a working paper. The working paper version is slightly longer - it includes some sections I omitted from the submitted version. It also uses a slightly different style sheet and styling options.

Currently, whenever I want to make a change, I have to make it in both versions, which is very inefficient.

How can I maintain both versions together efficiently, without text duplication?

NOTE: In case that matters, I work with LyX.

Comment: it'd be good to use dedicated version control software, such as `git`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the different styles in two master documents that include the content as a child document, as as suggested in the [answer of scottkosky](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152815/3751). If the common and distinct blobs of the two versions are fairly coarse-grained, you could use one child per blob.

If however, the two versions differ on a finer granularity (paragraphs, sentences, figures), I would use a single child document and use *branches* to conditionally select the content. Basically, a branch is the LyX concept to describe a conditional part of the document that can easily be included or omitted from the output.

For the following, I went to *Document -> Settings -> Branches* and added two branches `WorkingVersion` and `JournalVersion`. Within the document, conditional parts are then included by *Insert -> Branch*:

[image]

If you include a child document with branches into a master document, you need to add the branches there as well (*Document -> Settings -> Branches*). In the respective dialog, you can than *(De-)Activate* the branches that should be included/excluded from the child.

Comment: I think this solution is better than mine because it allows for more fine-grained tuning. IIRC you can also put (sub)sections in branches but unfortunately LyX doesn't do it the most smoothly.

Comment: Thanks! I am missing one piece of the puzzle: how to tell each of the master documents to include a different branch from the child document?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: In the respective master, just add the two branches as well (*Documents -> Settings -> Branches*), but just *Activate* only the one you want to include.

Answer (score 7):

Go to Insert > File > Child Document. From there you can choose a .tex or .lyx file. Keep the shared content in one of those and include it in both. Or make a new .lyx file for each section and include the duplicated ones in both.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is keep the paper in a subversion repository. I then make a branch for the non-trunk version which I can switch to as I wish. It is then easy to propagate changes from trunk to branch or branch to trunk as required. I do this especially for stuff I have to convert to MS Word format for submission since tex4ht is fussy about things and it is easier to strip a lot of my formatting out, convert to odt and doc/docx but I don't want to lose that formatting in my standard, working version.